How to write a SQL MERGE query to generate history table
I am fairly new to the SQL and coming across a problem as below.
I have an EMPLOYEE table that gets refreshed every day with latest data. It has 5 columns:
EmployeeID, Name, Position, Location, Rate
I want to write a query that selects from EMPLOYEE table and writes records in EMPLOYEE_HISTORY table with a Start_Date and End_Date column if any value has changed since yesterday.
Example:
EMPLOYEE Table on Day 1:



EmployeeID
Name
Position
Location
Rate




1001
John Doe
Manager
CA
45


1002
Bob Roman
Analyst
DE
32



EMPLOYEE_HISTORY will be empty initially. After running the query on Day1, it should have all records with Start_Date as Day1 and End_Date as NULL:
Expected EMPLOYEE_HISTORY Table on Day 1:



EmployeeID
Name
Position
Location
Rate
Start_Date
End_Date




1001
John Doe
Manager
CA
45
Date1
NULL


1002
Bob Roman
Analyst
DE
32
Date1
NULL



EMPLOYEE Table on Day 2:



EmployeeID
Name
Position
Location
Rate




1001
John Doe
Manager
CA
45


1002
Bob Roman
Analyst
DE
35



Note: Bob's Rate has changed
After running the query on Day2, earlier record for Bob must be end dated and new record should be inserted.
Expected EMPLOYEE_HISTORY Table on Day 2:



EmployeeID
Name
Position
Location
Rate
Start_Date
End_Date




1001
John Doe
Manager
CA
45
Date1
NULL


1002
Bob Roman
Analyst
DE
32
Date1
Date2


1002
Bob Roman
Analyst
DE
35
Date2
NULL



I know it should be a MERGE statement using "WHEN NOT MATCHED" clause but not able to formulate it fully.

...why not just use Temporal Tables correctly in the first place? And what RDBMS are you using? Not all systems support MERGE INTO tgt USING src OUTPUT INTO....

I am using Databricks. I only have read permissions on the source EMPLOYEE table.

please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms and tag your database system you are using

You can handle this with a MERGE. Specifically you would want to search up "SCD2" or "Slowly changing dimension" with the keywords "Merge" and "Databricks". Databricks also has a slowly changing dimension type delta table that will handle this logic for you if you find that writing the SCD2 Merge logic too daunting.

You could handle it with triggers using before and after update.  Before update, you find the original record in history without an end date and update the end date.  after update you simply add the same record to history with a new start date.   Triggers ensure all updates are made to history even if someone makes a direct update and doesn't know about the history.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

MERGE INTO EMPLOYEE_HISTORY AS EH
USING EMPLOYEE AS E
ON EH.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
WHEN MATCHED AND (EH.Name <> E.Name OR EH.Position <> E.Position OR EH.Location <> E.Location OR EH.Rate <> E.Rate) THEN
    UPDATE SET EH.End_Date = CURRENT_DATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (EmployeeID, Name, Position, Location, Rate, Start_Date, End_Date)
    VALUES (E.EmployeeID, E.Name, E.Position, E.Location, E.Rate, CURRENT_DATE, NULL)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET EH.End_Date = CURRENT_DATE
OUTPUT $action, inserted.EmployeeID, inserted.Name, inserted.Position, inserted.Location, inserted.Rate, inserted.Start_Date, inserted.End_Date;


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
